# Why is monerod not connecting to any peers?

Tags: monerod, peer-discovery

I've downloaded the latest Monero full node (0.10.2.1) for Linux (Ubuntu). When I run monerod from command line, I get the following error:

`Failed to connect to any of seed peers, continuing without seeds`

Using the log output, I see it keeps trying to connect to 213.167.231.2 and fails.

Any ideas for a fix?

Note: I've disabled all the firewalls on this box and punched port 18080 through the router firewall.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a really old Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

There is a problem with the seed nodes at the moment.
This is fixed in the coming release, hopefully in the next day or two: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1879

In the meantime, you can supply a node to start from:
`./monerod --add-peer 107.152.130.98:18080 --add-peer 212.83.175.67:18080 --add-peer 5.9.100.248:18080`
(this is simply adding the first three fallback peers to the command line)

Comment: Where can I read more about those fallback peers?

Comment: Look for then in src/p2p/net_nde.in in the get_seed_nodes function.

Comment: I am still having this issue. The first time I ran monerod blocks were syncing (log level 2). Then recently when I restarted monerod to continue where it left off. All I get is connect failed to ___________:18080 , where blank is any ip.