# monerod doesn't connect to peers

Tags: monerod, mining, network, peer

I have installed the Monero GUI and it was giving some errors so I went back to the cli.  When I run ./monerod everything seems to work fine but when I do status it gives me -
`Height: 1346603/1346603 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 99.90 MH/s, v5, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 11m 57s`
Why is it not connecting to peers? When I do start_mining  it gives the error `Error: Mining did not start -- BUSY`. I looked at [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3861/why-is-monerod-not-connecting-to-any-peers) to try and solve my issue but it still did not connect. I am using Ubuntu 17. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell without more information.

If you'd left monerod not running for a long time, it's plausible that it'll try to contact nodes which were running, but are not (either they're now down, or they were on dynamic IPs which changed since, etc).

It is also possible that peers banned your node. This would normally only happen if your node is on a bad fork and sends incorrect data to those other nodes. Check you are using monerod 0.10.3.1.

Another possibility is that your network connectivity is down.

To check what the network layer is doing: `set_log 1`.

To try and reset the set of known peers: exit monerod, rm ~/.bitmonero/p2pstate.bin, start monerod again

Comment: I am using monero 0.10.3.1 and connected to the internet while I am running monerod, I also reset the known peers with no avail. I have been getting a warning "no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received" But I read somewhere else that it wasn't an issue.  When I set log_level one I get many errors and warnings, the most prevalent are "-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT". I restarted monerod just to see if I would get the same errors and I had no output besides the dns warning.

Comment: The DNS warnings are indeed ignorable at this pont. Timeouts are also ignorable, they're typically about trying to reach nonexistent nodes.

Comment: Then what am I to do? None of the options above worked.

Comment: What is the top hash shown when you run the `diff` command ?

Comment: TH: f67cfa6b68c204d2f0ad7af2bbcfd5b233fba400a24bb7152ce11e5cc63f2ab2

Comment: OK, that's a valid block on the chain. The best thing at this point is to file a bug on github.com/monero-project/monero/issues with the information above, plus the log you get by restarting monerod with this flag: --log-level 1,net.cn:DEBUG,net.p2p:DEBUG